# How can I override the CSS ul menu for the JavaScript autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a search page with autocomplete for the first textbox, but when I developed it I found out that the ul/li CSS classes for the main menu styling are affecting the JavaScript list. How can I overwrite the styling of the menu to display a normal list? 

I'm a beginner programmer, so any help - also for coding suggestions - would be very useful!

Here's the code of the page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GameEnkaku - Homepage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bodyStyle.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/menuStyle.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/flexStyle.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/fonts.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/tableRightStyle.css"/>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            var aziende = [
            "APh Technology Consultants", 
            "Advanced Microcomputer Systems", 
            "Atari",
            "Bill Pitts e Hugh Tuck", 
            "Bullet-Proof Software, Nintendo", 
            "Bungie", 
            "Bungle, Gearbox, MacSoft Games", 
            "Capcom", 
            "Cing", 
            "Core Design", 
            "Crystal Dynamics", 
            "DMA Design", 
            "Electronic Arts Tiburon", 
            "Extended Play Productions", 
            "Game Freak", 
            "Ganbarion", 
            "Good Science Studio", 
            "Gottlieb", 
            "HAL Laboratory", 
            "Intelligent Systems", 
            "Intelligent Systems, Nintendo SPD", 
            "Kee Games", 
            "Konami",
            "Konami, Factor 5",
            "Konami, Ultra Games" 
            ];
        $( "#aziende" ).autocomplete({source: aziende});
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-container">
            <header>
                <div class="wrapper"><img class="resize" src="Immagini/homepageWallpaper.jpg" alt="Promo"></div>
                <img class="logo" src="Immagini/logo.png" alt="GameEnkaku Logo">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">La Storia &#9662;</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="origini.html">Le origini</a></li>
                            <li><a href="anni60-70.html">Anni '60 e Anni '70</a></li>
                            <li><a href="anni80-90.html">Anni '80 e Anni '90</a></li>
                            <li><a href="anni2000.html">Il nuovo<br>Millennio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="anni2010.html">Il Futuro</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Le Console &#9662;  </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="generazione1.php">I generaz.</a></li>
                            <li><a href="generazione2.php">II generaz.</a></li>
                            <li><a href="generazione3.php">III generaz.</a></li>
                            <li><a href="generazione4.php">IV generaz.</a></li>
                            <li><a href="generazione5.php">V generaz.</a></li>
                            <li><a href="generazione6.php">VI generaz.</a></li>
                            <li><a href="generazione7.php">VII generaz.</a></li>
                            <li><a href="generazione8.php">VIII generaz.</a></li>
                            <li><a href="generazione9.php">Uscite future</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Videogiochi &#9662;</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="arcadeLista.php">Arcade</a></li>
                            <li><a href="cartucceLista.php">Cartucce</a></li>
                            <li><a href="cdLista.php">CD/DVD</a></li>
                            <li><a href="downloadLista.php">Digital Download</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Approfondimenti &#9662;</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="letteratura.html">I videogiochi e la letteratura</a></li>
                            <li><a href="multiplayer.html">Il multiplayer online</a></li>
                            <li><a href="eSports.html">What are eSports?</a></li>
                            <li><a href="curiosita.html">Curiosit&agrave; e risorse</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="ricerca.php">Ricerca</a></li>
                </ul>
            </header>
            <section class="content">
            <div class="article">
            <h2>Ricerca nel Database</h2>

            Inserire solo il campo rispetto a cui si intende eseguire la ricerca<br><br>

            <FORM name=form1 action="risultati_ricerca.php" method="post">

            <label for="aziende">Sviluppatore/azienda: </label>
            <input id="aziende" type="text" name=aziende><br><br>

            <!--<INPUT id="aziende" >!-->

            Anno di uscita:
            <INPUT type="text" name=ANNO><br><br>

            Genere videogioco:
            <INPUT type="text" name=GENERE><br><br>

            Modalit&agrave; videogioco:
            <INPUT type="text" name=MODALITA><br><br>

            <input type="reset" value="Reimposta">
            <input type="submit" value="Cerca">

            </FORM> 
            </div>
            </section>
            <footer>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>La Storia</th>
                        <th>Le Console</th>
                        <th>Videogiochi</th>
                        <th>Approfondimenti</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="origini.html">Le origini</a></td>
                        <td><a href="generazione1.php">I generazione</a></td>
                        <td><a href="arcadeLista.php">Arcade</a></td>
                        <td><a href="letteratura.html">I videogiochi e la letteratura</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="anni60-70.html">Anni '60 e Anni '70</a></td>
                        <td><a href="generazione2.php">II generazione</a></td>
                        <td><li><a href="cartucceLista.php">Cartucce</a></li></td>
                        <td><li><a href="multiplayer.html">Il multiplayer online</a></li></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="anni80.html">Anni '80 e Anni'90</a></td>
                        <td><a href="generazione3.php">III generazione</a></td>
                        <td><a href="cdLista.php">CD/DVD</a></td>
                        <td><a href="eSports.html">What are eSports?</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="anni2000.html">Il nuovo Millennio</a></td>
                        <td><a href="generazione4.php">IV generazione</a></td>
                        <td><a href="downloadLista.php">Digital Download</a></td>
                        <td><a href="curiosita.html">Curiosit&agrave; e risorse</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="anni2010.html">Il Futuro</a></td>
                        <td><a href="generazione5.php">V generazione</a></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a href="generazione6.php">VI generazione</a></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a href="generazione7.html">VII generazione</a></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a href="generazione8.php">VIII generazione</a></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a href="generazione9.php">Uscite future</a></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p class="footerp">GameEnkaku - Angela Bertoncini - 2016</p>
            </footer>
            </div>
        <body>
<html>
```

Here's the CSS menu style:

```
/*Fonts area*/
@font-face {    
   font-family: "Neuropol";
   src: url("Fonts/neuropol.ttf") 
   format("truetype"); 
   } 
/*Fonts area*/


 ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        border-style: solid none;
        border-color: lightblue;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
 ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-align: left;
    }
 ul li a{
        font-family: "Neuropol";
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
 ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: #0066ff;/*#939393;*/
    }
    header ul li ul.dropdown{
        min-width: 125px; /* Set width of the dropdown */
        background: #f2f2f2;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
    }
 ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
        display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }
 ul li ul.dropdown li{
        display: block;
    }
```

You can also find the original page at [this link](http://gameenkaku.altervista.org/it/ricerca.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS to the bottom of your style.

```
.ui-widget-content {
 max-width:250px;
}

.ui-widget-content li{
 display:block;
 padding:10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.ui-menu-item.ui-state-focus{
 background:#0066FF;
 color:white;
}
```

Comment: The CloudFlare cashing was deceiving me 'cause it didn't show me the modification until I disabled it. Now it works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!